# Query for specific columns sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, planetscale, jasync-sql

I have the table soldiers:

```
class Soldier(Base):
    __tablename__ = "soldiers"

    id = Column(String(36), default=lambda: str(uuid4()), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    service_number = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    commander_id = Column(String(36), nullable=False, index=True)
    created_at = Column(Date, nullable=False, default=func.now())
```

and this async query:

```
result = await db.execute(select(Soldier))
soldiers = result.scalars().all()
```

db comes from here:

```
async def get_db():
    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    db = AsyncSession()
    try:
        print("connection opened")
        yield db
    finally:
        print("connection closed")
        await db.close()
```

For the problem itself. How do I query only for specific columns? I'm using a MySQL db hosted on planetscale (vitess)

The result when trying this is a list of the first column argument, say its id - so I get an array of id's in the response:

```
result = await db.execute(select(Soldier.id, Soldier.name, Soldier.service_number))
soldiers = result.scalars().all()
```

also tried using this but same result:

```
result = await db.execute(select(Soldier).with_only_columns(Soldier.id, Soldier.name, Soldier.service_number))
soldiers = result.scalars().all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Session.scalars()`, it will deliver the first "column" of each
row. If your `select()` is on a model, such as `select(Soldier)`, it will return
a list of tuples of the form: `(Soldier(...),)` (a one element tuple with the
soldier object), so using `.scalars()` will return a list of `Soldier` objects.
`Session.scalars()` is a convenience method for this case.

But when you selected specific columns (like
`select(Soldier.id, Soldier.name, Soldier.service_number)`), you will want to
use the result directly, since a list of tuples of the form
`(id, name, service_number)` will be returned. If you used `scalars` on it, you
will only get the first column, which is `id` here.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer! much appreciated. the docs are terrible on this

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```py
async def get_soldiers():
    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
        stmt = select(Soldier.id, Soldier.name, Soldier.service_number)
        result = await session.execute(stmt)
        soldiers = result.scalars().all()
        return soldiers
```

put your prefered columns on the satement